# How to check, if a user is admin using OAuth2 with Google Endpoints (Android App and Java)?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, admin, endpoints

I am currently developing an Android app that uses Google end points and OAuth2. I would like to use the built in App Engine roles (owner, developer and viewer) to check if the user is an administrator or not. OAuth is working fine and I can pass the User object to my back-end as a method parameter but I have tried both the OAuthService and UserService isUserAdmin() methods, to check if the user is admin, and both return a null value (looks like both require a cookie and the user to be logged in). Is there an equivalent isUserAdmin() method or option for End Points? The backend is written in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: I am running into the same issue, i'll let you know if i find anything.

Comment: Thanks Dre, please do! I have moved on with my project for now and have just added an Admin property to the datastore (far from ideal), but i will get back to this.